# What Vim plugins are useful for editing almost any file type?

Tags: vim, gvim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Most useful Vim plugin?](https://superuser.com/questions/9164/most-useful-vim-plugin)

What Vim plugins are useful for editing almost any file type?

Answer (score 1):

Check the answers on [Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21725/favorite-gvim-plugins-scripts) & [Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/9164/most-useful-vim-plugin)